# lxrandr fails to launch and throws Segmentation fault

Tags: command-line, xorg, lightdm, display-resolution, lxrandr

This has been quite specific scenario but since I haven't found anywhere a single clue how to solve this I thought it's probably not a bad idea to document how I solved it.

**Background**

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04, deployed with Kiwi builder (rather minimalist build
  as the goal was to have possibly lightweight system)
- Display Manager: lightdm
- Windows Manager: Openbox

**Symptom**

Attempt to launch lxrandr from Openbox apps menu gives no effect.
Attempt to launch lxrandr from terminal window prints:

```
    Segmentation fault
```

Nothing else - no core dump, no other errors, nothing in dmesg or any system logs. xrandr itself works just fine, other visual frontends for XRandR (eg. arandr) worked fine as well.
Reinstalling lxrandr did not fix the issue - even though there clearly was something missing, so one would expect that missing bit to be installed as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

**Troubleshooting**

As an act of desperation I tried debugging with gdb however I did not manage to get anything useful from that:

```bsh
    $ gdb lxrandr
    [..]
    Reading symbols from lxrandr...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/2d/cfbc3d5bd314c17b42e61b059377536fe93831.debug...done.
    done.

    (gdb) run       
    Starting program: /usr/bin/lxrandr 
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe8c8) at lxrandr.c:783
    783 lxrandr.c: No such file or directory.

    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x00005555555574a2 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe8c8) at lxrandr.c:783
```

**Solution**

Using another installation of Ubuntu 18.04 where lxrandr worked without any issues I managed to pinpoint the missing package to be X.Org X server Display Driver.
In case you are not sure which driver to use you may simply run:

```bsh
    apt install xserver-xorg-video-all
```

In my case – since it was a Virtual Machine - it was enough to run:

```bsh
    apt install xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

then reboot (or restart X) to solve the issue.